# Why does NARAKU NINJA wish to slay other NINJA?

Tags: ninja-slayer

DŌMO, I am SENSHIN.

Fujikido Kenji's NINJA Soul is that of NARAKU NINJA, a NINJA who wishes to slay NINJA. And thus, Fujikido becomes NINJA Slayer. I understand why Fujikido wishes to slay NINJA - his family was killed by the NINJA of the SŌKAIYA, so of course he would want to perform FUKUSHŪ<sup>1</sup>.

But what is NARAKU NINJA's motivation? What drives him - a NINJA himself - to slay other NINJA indiscriminately?

---

<sup>1</sup> Note: FUKUSHŪ means REVENGE.

Comment: Why do you use ALL CAPS and stuffs? I also see you rolling back Vogel612's revision. From what I can see, Wikipedia doesn't use ALL CAPS for those terminologies.

Comment: I am merely keeping with [the style of the official subtitles](https://www.google.com/search?q=viewster+ninja+slayer&oq=&tbm=isch).

Comment: It's likely that Naraku-*san* might not be one spirit, but rather a collective of vengeful spirits bent to revenge against the ninjas that killed them.  Nakraku can mean "hell" or  rather "abyss." As Fujikido laid dying, his lust for vengeance against those ninja that killed his family probably was on the same wavelength as the Naraku spirit, attracting one to another. As to the real identity of the spirit, followers of the manga would probably have a better idea.